# jersey: how to customize mapping body to bean?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I've got super specific logic of mapping content of the body to bean. I tried to use `ParamConverterProvider` but it works only for `@PathParam`, `@QueryParam` and etc.

Is there simple way of customizing mapping body to bean?

Answer (score 0):

In jersey it uses provided reader types to convert from the request body to arbitrary types. You'll want to implement [MessageBodyReader](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.9/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) with your bean.

Be sure to annotate your reader with @Provided and make sure it's explicitly registered in your ApplicationConfig or in a package that will be automatically scanned.

You shouldn't annotate your method that takes in the bean:

```
@Get
...
public Response doGet(MyBeanType bean) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another (dirty!) Approach could be to accept an Object and transform the object into your needed Pojo-Structure.
This of course depends of the structure which is handed in. Just debug to find out how your object looks like.

```
@Get
public Response doSome(Object o){
     if (o instanceof List) { .... }
}
```

Anyway, this should better be done with a MessageBodyReader as John H suggested!